# Translating the object with glm so that it follows the mouse cursor

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

So here is what I want to do. I want to implement a translation with my mouse so that the object I am translating will follow my mouse movement i.e if my mouse cursor moves by a certain amount of pixels X I want the object to move by that exact same amount X.

So far for rotations I have been using glm to implement arcball and I get a rotation matrix thanks to that.

I am using openGL and SDL so that getting my mouse coordinates is not difficult.
I can create a vector of size 3 with the current mouse coordinates during a mouse motion event with:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case  SDL_MOUSEMOTION: 
            glm::vec3 vecTranslation(event.motion.x, event.motion.y, 0);
            glm::mat4 translationMatrix ;
            glm::translate(translationMatrix, vecTranslation) ;

        }
    }
```

With that I have a translation matrix, but that will not get me a translation following exactly what the mouse cursor did in the end.

Would anyone have some insights on it?

Besides, to get my final projection matrix so as to call `glMulMatrix()`, I do:

```
glm::matrixCompMult(translationMatrix,rotationMatrix);
```

But when I do so, both translation and rotation don't work. If I simply return the rotation matrix and use it directly with `glMulMatrix()`, my arcball behaves as expected, but if I use the code above, I can only see one face of the cube that I have and it keeps on changing its proportions but never rotates nor translates.

As for the code that I use for the drawing:
     //Assume some code is done to know if and what translations should be done
     matrixProjection = translationMatrix * mMatNow * scaleMatrix ;
     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMultMatrixf(matrixProjection);
        // scaling transfomation 
        glScalef(0.5,0.5,0.5);
        drawCube();

```
    glFlush(); 
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
```

The matrix that I get is something like:
First:

1    ; 0     ; 0     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 1     ; 0     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 0     ; 1     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 0     ; 0     ; 1     ;

Then after a translation:

1    ; 0     ; 0     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 1     ; 0     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 0     ; 1     ; -25   ; 
0    ; 0     ; 0     ; 1     ;

So apparently the translation does happen, however I get this weird result on my drawing:[image: Translated image]

Original drawing: [image: Original Drawing]

Comment: If you're down voting and voting to close please state why. Questions cannot be improved without feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the position of your mouse-courser and of the object you want to move.

The easiest way to let your object follow your mouse would be to set its position to the position of the mouse:

one way: lets say you have vec3(10, 10, 4) as your mouse position, then simply set

```
. . . 10
. . . 10
. . . 4
0 0 0 1
```

(of yourse dont write dots)
as the objects matrix. For this it is neccessary that you the mouse position is not the location on the window but the location in the world.

another way:
add an in variable in your vertex-shader like this:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 inputPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 inputOffset;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 inputColor;

out vec4 color;

uniform mat4 worldMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = worldMatrix * vec4(inputPosition + inputOffset, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = viewMatrix * gl_Position;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * gl_Position;

    color = inputColor;

}
```

where the offset is your mouse-position vector. This approach doesnt attach the object to your mouse but moves it with it.
Also for every object you dont want to move you need another shader.

Edit:
If you want to rotate the object that it points to your courser, the easiest way would be to take the middle of that object as a vector and calculate the distance between mouse position and object vector. Then you can do some math to get the right angle and rotate the object.

Edit2:

Try the following: I also once had the problem that my matrix before translation was the same like after translation. This was because he did overwrite the matrix anyhow.
What I did: 
First, to make it easier, make a glm::vec3 with the position of your Object. eg. vec3(0,0,0).
Then draw your quad that it's center is at the left upper corner of screen. If you now update the position vector of your quad with your mouse position, the mouse respresents the center of the quad.
So every frame you do the following: 
pseudo code:

```
    positionQuad.x = event.motion.x; 
positionQuad.y = 0;
    positionQuad.z = event.motion.y;
    translationMatrix = glm::translate(positionQuad); // Declare translationMatrix as global/class variable to have access anywhere. glm translate multiplies the translation vector (vec4(mX, 0, mZ, 1) with an identity matrix. This works because we initialized the quad at upper left corner
    render(); // translationMatrix now is the model matrix. in render you still have to build the MVP matrix and draw it like always.
```

With rotation simply add

```
glm::rotate(translationMatrix, DEGREES, glm::vec3(0,1,0)); //this changes the current model-matrix by rotating it by DEGREES degrees around the axis specified in the vec3. If you do it otherwise like translationMatrix= glm::rotate.... you would overwrite the Matrix and you wont have any translation anymore.
```

after the translation and before the render

Comment: Will try that ASAP and let you know how it goes. I may have some questions anyway ^^

Comment: Ultimately it doesn't help as I would like to get use the functions used in GLM directly. There seems to be the translate function but it just doesn't work

Comment: There are multiple reasons for it. first: How is the mouse X and Y calculated? Do you get screen coordinates (e.g. 523, 445) or do you get deltas? (1.456, 0.235). If you get deltas, you dont really move the object as the position resets if you dont move the mouse. Another thing, try yourMatrix = glm::translate(vec3(mouseX, mouseY, 0)); , this is how i do translations. then i rotate doing this: yourMatrix = glm::rotate  (yourMatrix, degrees, vec3( 0,1,0)). if you dont do it this way, you may overwrite yourMatrix and it doesnt translate anymore. Also I use shaders to draw the MVP afterwards

Comment: I do use the mouse coordinates directly. I'm going to update the question with more complete code and the matrix I get so you can see.

Comment: Please see the edit of my question. I added some more code and new images. Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: I just saw an error in what I have posted. The matrix i originally have is not good. So that the translation is in fact working. It's just that I don't understand why I am getting this exact translation and the result on the image. Sorry for the mistake, especially now that you have written an edited answer. See edit please.

Comment: You have moved the quad 25 units in negative z direction so everything in the result Image is fine except that i dont know where the other colors come from.  Do you have an orthogonal or cone projection?

Comment: I have a cube with 6 different color on each face. So the other colors come from here. I guess the part that I dont understand is why it is motiving in the z direction. I'll keep you posted tomorrow after I check the code again. It is fairly late in my country.

Comment: Ah i guess i now See the Problem: okay: you moved the cube in -z direction so now the camera is inside the cube.  moving it with the mouse will have you to move it along x and y. So just change your translation that mousex affects x position and mousey y position

Comment: Also, you seem only to move the yellow faces. you dont move the whole cube. check if the transformation is applied for the whole one

Comment: Thanks to your inputs I partially solved my problem. Indeed I was passing the wrong translation parameters to the glm::translate() function, and I was over and over again translating the already previously translated matrix, giving me crazy translations at some points. However I still don't know why only the yellow face is translated. Working on that now

Comment: Probably this problem with just z translating is the topic of an other post. I accept you answer and thank you again for the help. Though if you have ideas on why it would only translate in the z direction let me know here if you want :). Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83683/discussion-between-lbesancon-and-eskalior).

Comment: maybe still a small question, but asking in chat to avoid long discussions in comments :)